# primefaces drag from one tree and drop to other tree

Tags: primefaces, tree, drag

I have two trees, one draggable and one droppable:

```
<p:tree value="#{myBean.selectedClassifiedOperation.root1}"
        var="node" selectionMode="single" id="tree1"
        selection="#{myBean.selectedLeftNode}" draggable="true" 
        dragdropScope="demo">       
        <p:ajax event="dragdrop" listener="#{myBean.onDrop}"
                 update=":#{p:component('messages')}" />
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{myBean.onNodeLeftSelect}"
                 update=":#{p:component('inputs')},:#{p:component('outputs')}" />

         <p:treeNode>
                 <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
         </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>

<p:tree value="#{myBean.selectedClassifiedOperation.root2}"
              var="node" selectionMode="single" id="tree2"
              selection="#{myBean.selectedRightNode}"  droppable="true"
              dragdropScope="demo" >
        <p:ajax event="dragdrop" listener="#{myBean.onDrop}"
                update=":#{p:component('messages')}" />
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{myBean.onNodeRightSelect}"
                update=":#{p:component('inputs')},:#{p:component('outputs')}" />

        <p:treeNode>
             <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
         </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

The problem is that the listener does not fire. It only fires when both trees are draggable and droppable. But it is not my case.
I use primefaces 5.1.
Is there any solution on this?

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this use case. What I did to make it worked is I place both `draggable` and `droppable` tags in the source p:tree and only `droppable` tag for the destination tree. In your case:

```
<p:tree value="#{myBean.selectedClassifiedOperation.root1}"
        var="node" selectionMode="single" id="tree1"
        selection="#{myBean.selectedLeftNode}" draggable="true" droppable="true" ... </p:tree>


<p:tree value="#{myBean.selectedClassifiedOperation.root2}"
              var="node" selectionMode="single" id="tree2"
              selection="#{myBean.selectedRightNode}"  droppable="true" ... </p:tree>
```